# Is there a keybinding to quick fix all in vs code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I copied the code below and want to quick fix `all` imports

does anybody know what is the keybinding for that in vs code?

[image]

Comment: How about `Ctrl + .`, `arrow down`, `Enter` ?

Comment: That sounds good :)
but I have to move the cursor to the error line then ```Ctrl + . ``` works,
looking for a keybinding